# How to compile nodejs

Tags: node.js, compilation

I am wondering can I compile a nodejs file from mytestfile.js to mytestfile so I can run it on linux like this ./mytestfile ?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to the very top of the .js file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

You might have to change the file permission and make it an executable:

```
chmod +x mytestfile.js
```

Example mytestfile.js:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// Grab provided args.
const [,, ...args] = process.argv

// Print hello world provided args
console.log(`Hello World ${args}`)
```

Comment: Thank you very much , I will give it a try

Comment: You can even remove the `.js` at the end of the file's name if you want to run it as `./mytestfile`

Comment: Here's a deeper explanation on how this works https://alexewerlof.medium.com/node-shebang-e1d4b02f731d (I hope this link is still valid when you visit it)

Comment: I thought this only worked on linux unless that is what the question wanted

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of very good and well maintained packages that do that.
I can't tell you which is better. Try both [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg) and [nexe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nexe)

Comment: Thank you very much , I will check them out.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you might get to acheiving your goal is to create a self-executing Javascript bytecode wrapper.

A project that does this is [`pkg`](https://github.com/vercel/pkg)

It somehow creates a self-contained binary executable from Javascript, including module dependencies and asset files and produces a self-contained executable.

Installation and use is easy:

```
$ npm install -g pkg
$ pkg index.js -o my-program
$ ./my-program
```

My understanding is that this binary contains nodejs bytecode.  It also appears that you can cross-compile.

Answer (score 0):

After having the same issue, I have done this using [Bun](https://bun.sh/). It worked like a charm. I have added an entry to script in package.json, like this:

```
"scripts": {
   "compile": "bun build src/main.ts --compile --outfile out"
```

I now run it like `bun run compile` and i can use the out file like `./out`